# Code Coverage - Blue versus Red

Tags: apex, trigger, class, code, code-coverage

I have various ranges of code that never show as "covered" in Apex Tests.  Here are two examples.  Could someone give me some guidance on them?  How would I cover them?

One:  **((Just the Database.update is marked RED))**

```
  PiggybackTriggerManager.PBOppFromAccountCheck = true;
  if( !updateMap.containsKey((String)accObj.get('Id') ) ) { //check that Acc Id not already added
      updateMap.put((String)accObj.get('Id'), (Account)accObj);

      if(updateMap.size() >= 199) {
          Database.update( updateMap.values() ); 
      }
  }
```

Another:  **((Everything except the IF is marked RED))**  EDIT: **The first IF is BLUE**

```
  if ( tempIsSubGapDetect == true )    {
      accObj.put('pb_FrstSubEnd_' +  tempFieldName + '__c',   temp_FirstSubEnd);   
      accObj.put('pb_FrstGapLen_' +  tempFieldName + '__c',   temp_FirstGapLen);   
      accObj.put('pb_LtstGapLen_' +  tempFieldName + '__c',   temp_LatestGapLen);  
      accObj.put('pb_TotNumGaps_' +  tempFieldName + '__c',   temp_TotalGaps);   
      if ( temp_TotalGapLen > 0 && temp_TotalGaps > 0 ) { 
         tempGapDivValue = temp_TotalGapLen / temp_TotalGaps; }
      else { 
         tempGapDivValue = null; }
      accObj.put('pb_AvgGapLen_' +   tempFieldName + '__c',   tempGapDivValue ); 
  }
```

In the second one, I can only assume MAYBE I have to replicate the VARIABLE NAMES being used to "assemble" my Field Names in the PUT statements??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your test methods don't have the correct data to trigger the branching.

1. Are you sure that updateMap.size() is at least 199?
2. Are you sure that tempIsSubGapDetect is ever true?

You will need to verify that you have enough test classes and data to trigger all of the branches.

Comment: #1 makes sense to me, so I'm going to try adding a couple For loops to the class to replicate some test Opps to fix that...

Comment: #2 I don't see the issue because my test class has various test Opps in it (which is what's relevant) and the GapDetect is a boolean read from a Custom Object of mine, based on "what product" the Opp is about.  (sigh)  I'm definitely making calls to some of our Subscription products (where gap detection is needed).  Still digging...

Comment: #2 Actually... since the IF is blue (I did not clearly state that), it's hitting True during code coverage.  So I'm back to wondering if the tempFieldName references are screwing it up.

Comment: It is _not_ blue on that line because the expression evaluated to true. The `if (expression) {` will be blue because that code is evaluated during the test run to test whether or not to enter the following block. The lines inside the `if` block are red (not covered) because the `if` block evaluated to `false` and the following code was skipped. You should verify this by adding an `else { system.debug('Evaluated false!'); }` to the code and then inspect the debug log. I would also suggest some debug statements for `updateMap.size()` and `tempIsSubGapDetect` to see what the variables contain.

Comment: Ahhhhhh.  I did not know to interpret it that way.  Wow.  Still digging...